# How to Insert Penalty for Page Breaking At Point?

Tags: page-breaking, page, penalty

I'm trying to figure out a way to insert a penalty for page breaking at a particular point similar to how the `\brokenpenalty` adds a penalty for page breaking after hyphenating a word. I want to insert a penalty for linebreaking at a particular point and an increased penalty for page breaking at that same point. For example, the penalty at that point could be 50 for line breaking and 100 for page breaking. (This is the same as the TeX defaults for `\hyphenpenalty` and `\brokenpenalty`, respectively.) I know that using `\penalty#` inserts of a penalty of # for line breaking at that point. This could be useful for penalising line/page breaks after Mr., Ms., Dr., etc. or between a number and its unit of measurements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\vadjust{\penalty100}\penalty50`   will insert a penalty of 50 for breaking the horizontal list and a penalty of 100 for breaking the vertical list (whether or not the hlist breaks at the penalty 50)

In LaTeX, `\nopagebreak[2]\nolinebreak[1]`would do more or less this, with different numeric values.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Is `\linebreak[1]\pagebreak[2]` equivalent to `\pagebreak[2]\linebreak[1]` ?

Comment: @User23456234 no, as `\pagebreak`, if used in hmode is "penalty for breaking after current line" so if the line breaks at `\linebreak[1]`  then `\pagebreak[2]\linebreak[1]` adds the page break penalty at that linebreak `\linebreak[1]\pagebreak[2]` adds it after  the next line. Just as `aaa\vspace{1cm}\\bbb`  adds 1cm space after aaa but `aaa\\\vspace{1cm}bbb` adds it after bbb

Comment: Did we make a mistake? I think we mean `\nopagebreak[2]` not `\pagebreak[2]`. I'm trying to discourage not encourage page breaks at particular points within a word or phrase.

Comment: @User23456234 sorry yes, I fixed the answer post

Comment: I am finding that using `\nopagebreak[1]\nolinebreak[1]` instead of `\nolinebreak[1]` (I am trying to discourage line and page breaks at some points) at Mr., Ms., Dr., etc. is causing several undesirable widows/orphans even though I have `\raggedbottom\widowpenalty=10000\clubpenalty=10000` Interestingly, all 3 widows/orphans exist in `itemize` or `enumerate` list structures.

Comment: @User23456234 adding a penalty adds a breakpoint